# Javascript filter() function to filter parent elements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter

I have a list of nested items in the JSON object. I have to filter only root nodes (parent).

The below is the JSON object.

```
const myJSON = [
    {
        __typename: 'Query', node:
        {
            __typename: 'Item', childItems: [Object], id: 'a', label: 'node1', url: '#', parent: null
        }
    },
    {
        __typename: 'Query', node:
        {
            __typename: 'Item', childItems: [Object], id: 'b', label: 'node2', url: '#', parent: null
        }
    },
    {
        __typename: 'Query', node:
        {
            __typename: 'Item', childItems: [Object], id: 'a', label: 'node3', url: '#', parent: 'node1'
        }
    }
]
```

this is my javascript code and the object is retrieved inside the object variable.

I want to filter only labels of parent nodes from the above object.

My desire output should be:
node1
node2
node3
node4

Comment: Your "JSON" is not valid. Looks like a copy paste of console output. Please provide the array in JavaScript literal notation.

Comment: yes, it is copied from the console. but it similar to that

Comment: If you want help, then provide code hat reproduces the problem. It is not to us to convert that console output to valid data.

Comment: menu [
  {
    __typename: 'Query',
    node: {
      __typename: 'Item',
      childItems: [Object],
      id: 'a',
      label: 'node1',
      url: '#',
      parent: null
    }
  },
  {
    __typename: 'Query',
    node: {
      __typename: 'Item',
      childItems: [Object],
      id: 'b',
      label: 'node2',
      url: '#',
      parent: null
    }
  }
]

Comment: @trincot due to the comment limit I posted only two items

Comment: With the JSON you just posted in the comment the code is working fine and filtering only those which have a null in `parent`

Comment: how to eliminate childItems and get the only label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to obtain only the desired properties after the `.filter()` method, you can use the `.map()` method to transform the final array.

Note that I changed `item.node.parent == null` to `!item.node.parent`. Like this it doesn't look just for those which are `null`, but for those which are *falsy*. Change it again to `null` if that is the behaviour you are expecting.

As you can see in the snippet, using `map`  can tell which property of the array I want to keep

**EDIT:** Answering your comment, of course you can select more than one property using the `.map()` method, as long as you format it as an object. The function `filterParentAndObtainLabelAndUrl(input)` returns label and url. As you can see, you can easily add as many as you want

```js
const filterParentAndObtainLabelValue = (input) => {
    return input.filter(element => !element.node.parent)
        .map(element => element.node.label);
}

const filterParentAndObtainLabelAndUrl = (input) => {
    return input.filter(element => !element.node.parent)
        .map(element => {
            return ({
                label: element.node.label,
                url: element.node.url
            })
        })
}

const inputJSON = [{ "__typename": "Query", "node": { "__typename": "Item", "childItems": [null], "id": "a", "label": "node1", "url": "#", "parent": null } }, { "__typename": "Query", "node": { "__typename": "Item", "childItems": [null], "id": "b", "label": "node2", "url": "#", "parent": null } }, { "__typename": "Query", "node": { "__typename": "Item", "childItems": [null], "id": "a", "label": "node3", "url": "#", "parent": "node1" } }]

console.log('Just the label: ', filterParentAndObtainLabelValue(inputJSON))
console.log('Label and url: ', filterParentAndObtainLabelAndUrl(inputJSON))
```

Comment: It is possible to return multiple values through map function like label and URL ?